# Is there a difference between these two code snippets, and if so what?

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

So I can't seem to figure out the difference between these two code snippets, or when one would be preferred over the other.
Snippet #1

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
           List testList = new ArrayList();
           testList.add(new Integer(6));

           String string = (String) testList.get(0);
     }
```

Snippet #2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList testList = new ArrayList();
       testList.add(new Integer(6));

       String string = (String) testList.get(0);
   }
```

My interpretation was that in snippet 1, a List named testList is being assigned to an ArrayList object. And in snippet 2 an ArrayList named testList is being assigned to an ArrayList object. However that just doesnt make sense to me.

Side question: Is one of the two a preferred standard?

Comment: I think this questions might have some duplicates

Comment: Both are bad since you are using raw-types instead of generics, and you are trying to read Integer as String (generics would protect you agains this mistake). Anyway first snippet is little better because you are programming on interfaces (we used `List` as type or `testList` interface since we doesn't really care how that list is implemented which gives us flexibility to change that implementation later if we want).

Comment: See this [article](http://www.fatagnus.com/program-to-an-interface-not-an-implementation) for more info.

Comment: Interfaces, amongst other things, allow you more flexibility in the future (if you need to change the type of collection you are dealing with)

Comment: Thank you very much for the article link, alot of confusion cleared in a few minutes of reading. Awesome article. @MaxZoom

Comment: @johnwoolstock Lots of `hard to grasp at first` concepts, but after a while it becomes second nature. See also [this one](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples.html) for more reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first snippet uses the interface `List` type, the second one uses the object type `ArrayList`.

Unless you really need any methods coming from `ArrayList`, you should use the interface type to prevent confusion about types.

Answer (score 1):

`List` is an interface. `ArrayList` implements `List`. So, functionally, both the snippets work same way.

Comment: Ah, do Java developers have a preference of which one is the standard implementation?